# How to create self-signed SSL cert on intranet server using IIS Manager : logged in as Admin but getting "access denied" error when saving the cert

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I need to create a self-signed SSL certificate on an *intranet* server that is running IIS. I'm logged in remotely to the server as admin and am opening IIS Manager as admin, and choosing Server Certificates then "Create Self-Signed Certificate" in the Actions pane of IIS Manager; but when I get to the point where the self-signed certificate is saved to Personal or Web Hosting, there is an "access denied" error, no matter which of the two is chosen. How to accomplish this task?

Comment: You will have to escalate this to your domain administrators. No one here can help much without accessing that machine.

Comment: I found a way to do it using PowerShell.  Not sure why IIS wouldn't let me save the cert.

Comment: I would use the command prompt. Adding IIS Manager is adding unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to grant read/write permissions to the administrator user of folder  C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys.

This should work.